# Pip does not install in venv

Tags: python, pip

Virtualenv stoped working on my machine, without me knowing what I changed.
It looks like pip install on global packages instead of venv. 
I checked all the related question on stackoverflow and could not find a answer that resolved my issue.

So here it is.
I'm using Manjaro and python 3.7.

What I do :

```
mkdir test_venv
cd test_venv
python3 -m venv env
```

> It effectivly creates the folder env with all the good stuff. The $VIRTUAL_ENV in the env/bin/activate is good  "/home/MyName/PythonProjects/test_venv/env"

```
which pip
```

> before activating the venv it returns /home/MyName/.local/bin/pip

```
source env/bin/activate
```

> I'm effectivly entering the venv

```
which pip
```

> returns /home/MyName/PythonProjects/test_venv/env/bin/pip and same for python3

```
pip install requests
```

> Installing collected packages: certifi, idna, urllib3, chardet, requests
>
> Successfully installed certifi-2019.6.16 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.8 requests-2.22.0 urllib3-1.25.3

And pip-freeze return nothing and trying to do an import requests in a test.py file return "No module named requests"

Do you have any ideas what could I try ? I tried to reinstall python-pip package with pacman, changed nothing.

Thanks !
Have a good day

Comment: *test.py*? It should contain `import requests` (**notice the *s*** at the end).

Comment: You might want to try something like this `/home/MyName/PythonProjects/test_venv/env/bin/python -m pip install requests`

Comment: @CristiFati thanks for spotting this typo, but unfortunatly it was just a type typing this in the forum

Comment: @sinoroc It does not look like it changed something :/

Comment: More details might help. Do `pip -V`, `pip config list`, `pip debug` say anything that might put you on the right track?

Comment: Also have a look at the file `pyvenv.cfg` in your virtual environment directory.

Comment: @sinoroc
Thank you for your response
In pipven.cfg I have home=/usr/bin is it ok ?
My version of pip in en venv is 19.0.3 (but I have a 19.2.3 on my usr)
pip config list return nothing.
What is pip debug ? Do you mean verbose ? Is that case I can't find anything weird, maybe : "changing mode of /home/myUser/.local/bin/chardetect to 755" I supposed it should by my venv.

Comment: In `pyvenv.cfg`, having `home=/usr/bin` is normal, but you should check that `include-system-site-packages = false`. Do the packages get actually installed somewhere? In your global site ? `pip debug` is available in newer versions of `pip`. `pip config list` returning nothing is not a bad thing so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, also with Python3.7 and Manjaro.
I found the fix [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57802296) for [Pip won't install packages in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57801495/pip-wont-install-packages-in-virtualenv).

Set the "user" parameter to false in "/etc/pip.conf".

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I've found that the problem was that I had moved the directory of my virtual environment to a new location, which is not a good idea as there are absolute paths created in some configuration files (e.g. in activate.csh).
Recreating my virtual environment on the new location fixed the issue.